# Listing Non Contiguous Data Without Blanks Horizontally?

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

So I'm trying to combine cells in a particular row into a horizontal list. There is tons of literature and tutorials about listing non contiguous data without blanks vertically but I can't seem to find one for horizontal lists. The image displays the end result I would like. I don't need to transpose it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(2:2,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(2:2<>""))*COLUMN(2:2),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 365 ,in **D6** enter:

```
=FILTER(2:2,2:2<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have 365 unfortunately. Can't update my Excel because of work, currently at 2019 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextJoin` to create a XML string from the row, omitting blank cells.  Then `FilterXML` to turn that string into a column range.  Then `Transpose` it into a row.  In Excel 20 you'll need to select enough cells to hold the result, and enter as an Array Formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

[image]